# localhost 8080 or 80 stopped working (differently)

Tags: apache, port, wamp

With Wamp64, over the last month I have succeeded in creating a non-trivial app (e.g., Node.js as gateway to ~1000 lines of php that builds another ~1000 of html/css/js.) But overnight my Windows 11 shut down. Some tinkering today got all wamp64's services cleanly restarted. But, at first, in Chrome or Edge, invoking my app yielded only: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
That was with my app using port:8080. I then discovered that the rebooted Apache is now using port:80. OK, whatever, but the failure makes sense. So I edited my app, wherever port was specified, to also use port 80. The result was really weird -- invoking my app (Edge or Chrome) now (after a slight but detectable pause) replaces its page with: WAMP's Localhost "WAMPSERVER Homepage" window. OK, let's change **everything** (Apache, wamp64 started and rebooted, the apps) back to 8080. Result: that same cursed WAMPSERVER Homepage. Now from both 80 and 8080, on Edge or Chrome. Will I never again see my beloved new app?

No diagnostic efforts help -- F12 with Edge, the Apache error log. I also tried turning off McAfee's firewall, and MS's Defender was already off.
I'm stuck. What else might I try? Where could this problem be? Should I reinstall something?

Comment: Please show **relevant sections** of configuration and log files. In addition, I think this question is probably a much better fit for the SuperUser stack exchange.